# How to get variation price in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin in one of my website. In this there are variation prices shown on product page. but when i am trying to get them it is only giving abobe price as shown in this url [have a look](http://ccm-dev.com/product/casoria/)

The code i am using for this is

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id'];
$variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
$sales_price = $variable_product1 ->sale_price;
echo $regular_price."<br/>".$sales_price;
```

but it is only priniting $1499 and $599. But i want to get $1800 and $899 shown abobe add to cart button. How to get them.

Comment: For info: The price you want to display is located in woocommerce templates > single-product > add-to-cart > variation.php

Comment: Yes but how to get these prices, like $1800 and $800 separate

Comment: The price is changing when seleting different size or foundation type,,,,so basically how can i get variation price based on size or foundation type ?